# Filtering array data with multiple conditions with ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I'm using an es6 filter function that takes in both search string and value from state hook that should allow the user to search data by a string, and then apply a filter property `a11yType` as well. I can filter the data by `a11yType` alone, or by search string alone, but unable to get both to work in tandem. Not sure what's going on here:

Search string hook (value taken from text input)

```
const [searchFilter, setFilter] = useState('');
```

Accessibility string value (value taken from button options)

```
const [a11yType, setA11yType] = useState('');
```

Data filtered and mapped

```
data &&
    data
        .filter(
            (f) =>
                f[0].includes(searchFilter.toUpperCase()) ||
                (searchFilter === '' && f[1].type === a11yType),
        )
        .map((item, i) => {
            {
                item[1].type &&
                    rows.push(
                        createData(
                            `${item[0]}`,
                            `${item[1].type}`,
                            `${[...new Set(item[1].urls)].length}`,
                            `${item[1].urls}`,
                        ),
                    );
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean "in tandem". You want both to match?

Comment: @slebetman - the filtering should take in a string value, and allow the user to select one of a set of buttons that set the `a11yType` value which is also a string. Basically search a string, and then toggle between one of three values to refine results.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. You want both the search and type to match?

Comment: @slebetman - yes, the search string should match a value, and the a11yType should also match a value. Results would include all cases where the search string value is in the `f[0]` and that result has a matching `a11yType` value.

Comment: Slightly unrelated side notes: 1. I like to avoid the function without a return statement unless it all fits cleanly in one line for legibility. 2. Calling `Array#map` without returning anything is an anti-pattern, use a for loop or `Array#forEach` for clarity and to avoid creating an extra array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the goal you want to achieve, but I think you've made a logical error.
First, you used the *or* operator in your statement. It checks whether at least one of the conditions is true. So you first check if the f[0] includes the searchString and if it doesn't it proceeds to the second statement.
Second, you check if the searchFilter is empty and if it does, you check if the f[1] type is equal to a11yType.
And this works just like you described it. You can only filter by the search phrase or by the a11yType if the search phrase is empty.
So if you want to combine two filters (check what results include a searchString and have a matching a11yType), just try this:

```js
f[0].includes(searchFilter.toUpperCase())
&& // only if the search string is contained in f[0]
(a11yType === '' || f[1].type === a11yType) // a11yType is empty or the result satisfies the filter
```

Comment: The logic is that you should be able to either filter just by search string, just by a11yType or a combination of the two. This appears to work, and I had just swapped the logic a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very specific with your boolean logic. The computer cannot guess what you mean (unlike talking to humans).

You want:

1. If user is searching but no type selected match the search
2. If user select type but not searching match the type
3. If user is both searching and selecting type match both

Therefore your filter function should be:

```
(f) =>
    (a11yType === '' && f[0].includes(searchFilter.toUpperCase())) ||
    (searchFilter === '' && f[1].type === a11yType) ||
    (f[0].includes(searchFilter.toUpperCase()) && f[1].type === a11yType)
```

In the short term this should fix your issue.

However, note that this will become quickly unmanageable the more conditions you add. Say you add another option: "category", your code will grow very big:

```
(f) =>
    (category === '' && a11yType === '' && f[0].includes(searchFilter.toUpperCase())) ||
    (category === '' && searchFilter === '' && f[1].type === a11yType) ||
    (category === '' && f[0].includes(searchFilter.toUpperCase()) && f[1].type === a11yType) ||
    (a11yType === '' && searchFilter === '' && f[1].category === category) ||
    (searchFilter === '' && f[1].type === a11yType &&  f[1].category === category) ||
    (f[0].includes(searchFilter.toUpperCase()) && f[1].type === a11yType  &&  f[1].category === category)
```

Not to mention it becomes very unreadable. I'm not sure just looking at the function above if the function is well-formed or if I have a syntax error - much less if the logic is correct!

For this kind of logic, one thing to note is that if the condition is empty then we ignore the condition. For the `.filter()` function, ignoring a condition means we always return `true`.

Refactoring the code we can do the following:

```
(f) => {
    const searchCond = searchFilter === '' || f[0].includes(searchFilter.toUpperCase()));

    const typeCond = a11yType === '' || f[1].type === a11yType;

    return searchCond && typeCond;
}
```

Basically we switch the logic from **OR** of **AND** (sum of products) to **AND** or **OR** (product of sums). This allows us to avoid typing the conditions twice. Notice that in the refactored code above we check `f[1].type === a11yType` only **once** instead of needing to retype it for the third case of matching both the search and the type.

In this way adding another option requires you to add only one more condition:

```
(f) => {
    const searchCond = searchFilter === '' || f[0].includes(searchFilter.toUpperCase()));

    const typeCond = a11yType === '' || f[1].type === a11yType;

    const categoryCond = category === '' || f[1].category === category;

    return searchCond && typeCond && categoryCond;
}
```

Of course, you can also write this in the compact form you seem to like:

```
(f) => 
    (searchFilter === '' || f[0].includes(searchFilter.toUpperCase()))) &&
    (a11yType === '' || f[1].type === a11yType) &&;
    (category === '' || f[1].category === category);
```